# In VB.net is there an option to force generation of the counter variable in the "Next" statement?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, variables, iteration, counter

Visual Basic .net automatically inserts a "Next" statement when you enter a "For" statement; e.g., if I type:

```
For i as integer = 1 to 10
```

a Next will automatically be inserted, so that the code looks like:

```
For i as integer = 1 to 10

Next
```

It is optional to put the counter variable ("i" in the above) in the Next statement, so that it would read:

```
Next i
```

I'd really like to make this the default, as it really helps when one has nested For statements.  I can't find anything in the Visual Studio settings to do this; maybe it's partly buried somewhere in Intellisense.  I thought perhaps *someone* out there has already figured this out.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to modify the `.snippet` file associated with the pattern. For the one you are looking for it is, by default:

> VisualStudioInstallDirectory\VB\Snippets\1033\common code patterns\conditionals and loops\ForEachNext.snippet

You can also track down the exact location by looking in

`Tools > Code Snippets Manager...`, select `Visual Basic` for the language and browse to `Code Patterns - If, For Each, Try Catch, Property, etc` - the file location will be listed there.

Comment: A good suggestion; however, OP is asking about an IDE Editor tweak.

Comment: That is how the IDE knows to implement the pattern. This is exactly what OP is looking for. If you let "intellisense" auto-complete a code block, it is using code snippets to generate the output.

Comment: Huh - I tried that before commenting after seeing the score tick to 1 (using VS 2013). Didn't seem to work. Only Snippets worked. Not the "Automatic insertion of end constructs" function of the editor.

Comment: I made direct edits in the snippet files to add the variable to the "Next" line, but after restarting Visual Studio I don't see any change.  I usually use something like:
for i as integer =1 to 10
next i
and I see that the snippet has no "as" clause; might that be the problem?
(I think I changed two snippets, on that would seem to cover the above, the other "for each...").  Both still show the same behavior.